# Read the text of WinCustom control

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a table which has rows. But instead of cells of table they are custom controls and I have to read the cell value.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: size of the table? (in Row*Col)

Comment: table has 2 rows and 2 columns(2*2)

Comment: Custom controls must include code to support MSAA or UIA for Coded UI to work. Ask the supplier or the author of the controls about how much support they have for MSAA or UIA.

Comment: The NativeControlType of control is displayed  as unknown object, is there is any way to get the text

Comment: Yes, but only if the custom control provides the required MSAA or UIA interfaces.

Comment: @Pratik..Can you be able to upload the screenshot of the UITestbuilder with properties after spying on the controls? that will give some clear ideas..